# How to negate a parser with Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I have a file with line endings “\r\r\n”, and use the parser `eol = string "\r\r\n" :: Parser String` to handle them. To get a list of the lines between these separators, I would like to use `sepBy` along with a parser that returns any text that would not be captured by `eol`. Looking through the documentation I did not see a combinator that negates a parser (an ‘anything but the pattern `”\r\r\n”`’ parser).

I have tried using `sepBy (many anyToken) end`, but `many anyToken` appears to be greedy, not stopping for `eol` matches. I cannot use `many (noneOf "\n\r")`, because there are several places in my text with the single `'\n'` character.

Is there a combinator that can get me the inverse of `string "\r\r\n"`?

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid you're going about it backwards. Parsec parsers don't chop up the input, they build the output.
The more you try to parse by thinking about what you don't want, the harder it'll be. You need to think bottom-up what's permissable, not top down where you chop.

You should start with the smallest, most basic thing you *do* want. For example, don't think of an identifier as everything before a space, think of it as a letter followed by alphanumeric data. You can then combine that, separated by whitespace with the other things you expect on a line.

```
line = do
       i <- identifier
       whiteSpace
       string "="
       e <- expr
       return $ Line i e
```

Only when you've completed a parser that successfully parses what you want from a line and rejects invalid lines should you parse multiple lines:

```
lines = sepBy line eol
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. In my case, I have a parser built from the ground up similar to yours, for most of the lines which follow a somewhat standard structure. For this question, I'm trying to build an 'everything else that doesn't match the structure' parser, which could cover everything from alphanumeric, newlines, some '\652…' type chars, or maybe even nothing at all in between the "\r\r\n" separators. In this case, would it not be more tedious to enumerate all of the possible characters, rather than the one sequence I don't want to capture? Or am I still thinking about it wrong?

Comment: @BirdJaguarIV Isn't there some structure between the "\r\r\n"? Surely you don't just want some random strings where absolutely anything goes? If there genuinely isn't, you're not parsing, just chopping and you could use a single application of splitOn from Data.List.Split, in the splits package. However, if you intend to then separate each line into meaningful data, you should define a pasrser for each substructure/bit of the data you want, before combining these with sepBy. If there are no rules, split, if there are rules, parse. Don't use a parser as a split function.

Comment: @BirdJaguarIV What's the data you're processing? Do you need to make sense of ech line or treat it as a single blob of uninteresting characters?

Comment: The data is basically a log file output by a chat client (that sometimes preserves empty fines). The structure for most lines is "[date] [speaker]: [message]", where message seems to be any potential character (alphanumeric, newline, weird characters that I've not sure how to classify—perhaps Unicode). Seemingly everything but `"\r\r\n"`.

It sounds like I should use `splitOn` on the list, and then map my parser, and filter on the things that succeed.

Comment: Oh OK, that _is_ very unstructured data. Parse the date, then the speaker, then `manyTill anyChar (try eol)` as you said. You don't need `splitOn`. If it were just the message, that would be a split, but there's enough structure before the message to justify parsing. The reason there's no simpler way is that it's rare to want large blobs of unstructured data when parsing - usually the data is more machine-meaningful.

Answer (score 6):

As a tentative answer, it looks like [`manyTill anyChar (try eol)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:manyTill) does what I want. As part of my original question though, I'm still interested in knowing whether there is a general way to negate a parser, or whether there's another recommended way of doing what I want.

Comment: Does notFollowedBy (in Text.Parsec.Combinator) help?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Tim, if I didn't already need a 'many' type parser, this would probably be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The
[`sepCap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:sepCap)
parser combinator from the package
[replace-megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/)
does this kind of parser negation, and returns a list of `Either` with the negative matches in `Left` and the positive matches in `Right`.

```hs
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec

parseTest (sepCap (chunk "\r\r\n" :: Parsec Void String String))
  $ "one\r\r\ntwo\r\r\nthree\r\r\n"
```

```hs
[ Left "one"
, Right "\r\r\n"
, Left "two"
, Right "\r\r\n"
, Left "three"
, Right "\r\r\n"
]
```